# My dropdown menu not working when I updating page with Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a sidebar in body and also I have a content section in body. You can think

```
<aside class="sidebar-left-collapse">

    <a href="#" class="company-logo">Logo</a>

    <div class="sidebar-links">

        <div class="link-yellow selected">
            <a href="katalog/camgurubu.html">
                KAPAK
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="link-blue">
            <a href="katalog/cam2.html">
                CAM GURUBU
            </a>
            <ul class="sub-links">
                <li><a href="#">Paşabahçe</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="link-red">
            <a href="#">
                PORSELEN GURUBU
            </a>
            <ul class="sub-links">
                <li><a href="#">KÜTAHYA PORSELEN</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">BONNA PORSELEN</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="link-yellow">
            <a href="#">
                ÇATAL/KAŞIK/BIÇAK
            </a>
            <ul class="sub-links">
                <li><a href="#">ARYILDIZ ÇATAL/KAŞIK/BIÇAK</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">ŞEHZADE ÇATAL/KAŞIK/BIÇAK</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">ALMOND ÇATAL/KAŞIK/BIÇAK</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">NARİN ÇATAL/KAŞIK/BIÇAK</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="link-green">

            <a href="#">
                MUTFAK SET ÜSTÜ MALZEMELERİ
            </a>

            <ul class="sub-links">
                <li><a href="#">DOLLY PLASTİK ÜRÜNLER</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">PİRGE BIÇAKLARI</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">VİCTORİNOX BIÇAKLARI</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">İTHAL MALZEME SET ÜSTÜ GRUBU</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">BORA SAKLAMA KABI VE DİĞER MALZEMELER</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">TÜRKAY POLİETİLEN GRUPLARI</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">CAMBRO ÜRÜNLERİ</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">PLASTİK,POLİKARBON MALZEMELER</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">KÜLSAN (THERMOSET MALZEMELER)</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">NARİN SET ÜSTÜ MALZEMELERİ</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">ARYILDIZ SET ÜSTÜ MALZEMELER</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">ALTINBAŞAK TEFLON TAVALAR,FAJİTA GRUPLARI, SET ÜSTÜ ÜRÜNLER</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">TEL KEVGİR, SÜZGEÇ, ÇIRPICI ÜRÜNLER GURUBU</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">KEPÇE, KEVGİR, SPATULA, MAŞA  SERVİS GRUPLARI</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">TRİBECA ÜRÜN GRUPLARI</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">ALKAN-ZİCCO ÜRÜN GRUPLARI</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">ÇÖP KOVALARI</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">TENCERELER</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">KAÇAROLA/KÜVETLER</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">DERİ ÜRÜNLERİ VE MENÜLER</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">PİZZA TAVALARI</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">FIRIN KÜREKLERİ</a></li>

            </ul>

        </div>
        <div class="link-green">

            <a href="#">
                AÇIK BÜFE EKİPMANLARI
            </a>

            <ul class="sub-links">
                <li><a href="#">İTHAL AÇIK BÜFE MALZEMELERİ</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">CHAFİNG DISH</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">BORA AÇIK BÜFE ÜRÜNLER</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">ALKAN-ZİCCO AÇIK BÜFE ÜRÜN GRUPLARI</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">GÜREN METAL AÇIK BÜFE ÜRÜNLERİ</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">KÜLSAN AÇIK BÜFE ÜRÜNLER</a></li>

            </ul>

        </div>
        <div class="link-green">

            <a href="#">
                PASTAHANE EKİPMANLARI
            </a>

            <ul class="sub-links">
                <li><a href="#">ARYILDIZ PASTAHANE ÜRÜNLERİ</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">PASTA,KEK KALIPLARI ALÜMİNYUM MALZEMELER</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>
        <div class="link-green">

            <a href="#">
                GENEL MALZEME GRUBU
            </a>

            <ul class="sub-links">
                <li><a href="#">PLASTİK TAŞIMA EKİPMANLARI VE AKSESUARLARI</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">KAHVE MAKİNALARI </a></li>
                <li><a href="#">AHŞAP SERVİS EKİPMANLARI</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>
        <div class="link-green">

            <a href="#">
                CİHAZLAR
            </a>

            <ul class="sub-links">
                <li>
                    <div class="link-green">
                        <a href="#">
                            HAZIRLIK
                        </a>
                        <ul class="sub-links">
                <li><a href="#"> Arda </a></li>
                <li><a href="#"> Zaman </a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"> Deneme</a></li>
                        </ul>

                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="link-green">
                        <a href="#">
                            KAFETERYA CİHAZLARI
                        </a>
            <ul class="sub-links">
                <li><a href="#"> Arda </a></li>
                <li><a href="#"> Zaman </a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"> Deneme</a></li>
                        </ul>

                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="link-green">
                        <a href="#">
                            BULAŞIKHANE
                        </a>
                        <ul class="sub-links">
                            <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                        </ul>

                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="link-green">
                        <a href="#">
                            PİŞİRME GURUBU 600 SERİ
                        </a>
                        <ul class="sub-links">
                            <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                        </ul>

                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="link-green">
                        <a href="#">
                            PİŞİRME GURUBU 700 SERİ
                        </a>
                        <ul class="sub-links">
                            <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                        </ul>

                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="link-green">
                        <a href="#">
                            PİŞİRME GURUBU 900 SERİ
                        </a>
                        <ul class="sub-links">
                            <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                        </ul>

                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="link-green">
                        <a href="#">
                            KONVEKSİYONLU FIRINLAR
                        </a>
                        <ul class="sub-links">
                            <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                        </ul>

                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="link-green">
                        <a href="#">
                            SOĞUTMA EKİPMANLARI
                        </a>
                        <ul class="sub-links">
                            <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                        </ul>

                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="link-green">
                        <a href="#">
                            TEŞHİR ÜRÜNLERİ
                        </a>
                        <ul class="sub-links">
                            <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                        </ul>

                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="link-green">
                        <a href="#">
                            RAF ÜRÜNLERİ
                        </a>
                        <ul class="sub-links">
                            <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                        </ul>

                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="link-green">
                        <a href="#">
                            TEZGAH/DAVLUMBAZ/YER SÜZGEÇLERİ
                        </a>
                        <ul class="sub-links">
                            <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                        </ul>

                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="link-green">
                        <a href="#">
                            ÇAMAŞIRHANE GRUBU
                        </a>
                        <ul class="sub-links">
                            <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                        </ul>

                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="link-green">
                        <a href="#">
                            İTHAL ÜRÜNLER
                        </a>
                        <ul class="sub-links">
                            <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                        </ul>

                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>

</aside>

<div class="main-content">

    <div class="menu">

        <section id="content">

        </section>

    </div>

</div>
```

When I update content section with ajax dropdown menu doesn't work. I think the problem is, menu selected class unchanged because ajax refresing page.

```
        var links = $('.sidebar-links > div');
    var links2 = $('.sidebar-links > div > ul.sub-links > li > div');

    links.on('click', function () {
        links.removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    });

    links2.on('click', function () {

        links2.removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected').show();

    });

    $('.sidebar-links div a').on('click' ,function(){
        var yol = $(this).attr('href');
        $(this).attr("href", "#");

        $.ajax({
                  async: true,
                  type: "GET",
                  url: yol,
                  success: function (html) {
                      $("#content").html(html);
                  }
              });
    });
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Is it your event handlers not firing?

Comment: Also, is the HTML above the output *after* your ajax request, or the static HTML *before* your ajax request?

Comment: The question isn't very clear, but I suspect it's a duplicate of [event binding on dynamically-created elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)